# How to ensure tuple is homogenous?

Tags: scala, tuples, dotty, scala-3

For reasons beyond my control, my method receives inputs in the form of a tuple. This tuple should only contain instances of `Foo`, i.e., it should look like `(Foo, Foo ... Foo)` and should not have `String` or `Int` inside. I want to check this at compile-time instead of throwing an exception at runtime. How can I achieve this?

Below is the code I currently have, which is not right:

```
def f(tupleOfFoos: Tuple): Tuple = {
  for (x <- tupleOfFoos) assert(x.isInstanceOf[Foo])
  mapTuple(tupleOfFoos, irrelevantFunction)
}
```

I am open to using Shapeless or the new features introduced in Dotty/Scala 3.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala 2, with Shapeless, you can do this ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zd7GRNsoSJiyfd85dkAMXg)):

```scala
def f[T <: Product, H <: HList](tupleOfFoos: T)(
  implicit gen: Generic.Aux[T, H], 
  hev: LiftAll[({type E[T] = Foo =:= T})#E, H]
) = tupleOfFoos
```

`LiftAll` ensures there's an instance of `Foo =:= X` for every `X` in `H`, and `gen` makes sure that `T` and `H` are not completely unrelated types.

---

In Dotty, you can add an evidence parameter with a match type for this:

```
type Homogenous[H, T <: Tuple] = T match {
    case EmptyTuple => DummyImplicit
    case H *: t => Homogenous[H, t]
    case _ => Nothing
}
    
def f[T <: Tuple](tupleOfFoos: T)(using Homogenous[Foo, T]) = tupleOfFoos
```

This will allow you to call `f((Foo(), Foo(), Foo()))` but not `f((1, 2, 3))`.

`Homogenous` is a recursive match type with a base case of `EmptyTuple`. If a tuple is empty, then it's not filled with non-`Foo`s, so the type becomes `DummyImplicit`, which has an implicit already in scope. Otherwise, we check if it looks like `(H, ...)` / `H *: t`, in which case we need to check if the rest of the tuple (`t`) is also valid. If it doesn't match that second case, we know the tuple is invalid, in which case the result is `Nothing`, which sane people don't make implicit values of.

If you want to use context bounds, you can make an additional curried type ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Wgv98g9iS2OgPCXWrZqGVw)):

```
type Homo2[H] = [T <: Tuple] =>> Homogenous[H, T]

def f[T <: Tuple : Homo2[Foo]](tupleOfFoos: T) = tupleOfFoos
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get it to work with a single curried type ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/IRkAmSN6RFOBssXh3rICKg)):

```
type Homogenous[H] = [T <: Tuple] =>> T match {
    case EmptyTuple => DummyImplicit
    case H *: t => Homogenous[H][t]
    case _ => Nothing
}
```